# How to webscrape scholar.google.com in Java?

Tags: java, web-scraping

I want to write a Java func `grabTopResults(String f)` such that `grabTopResults("automata theory")` returns me a list of the top 100 cited papers on scholar.google.com for "automata theory".

Does anyone have suggestions for what libraries will make my life easy?

Thanks!

Comment: I think google forbids such things. Check their terms of use

Comment: As long as the search is initiated by a person and not an aggregation script, I don't see that it violates Google's TOS. It says you have to use Google provided interfaces which you are (their http response) and that you can't automate it, which if a user initiates it it is basically just another form of a web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I'm sure Google can afford the bandwidth, I'll ignore the question of whether this is immoral/illegal/prohibited by Google's T&C

First thing you need to do is figure out what HTTP request (or requests) you need to issue in order to obtain the page with the data you need. Once you've figured this out, use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) to issue the same request from Java code. The previous link shows example code that explains how to do this.

Once you've downloaded the content of the relevant page, you'll need to use a HTML parser to extract the data you're interested in. The [Jericho parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) suggested by peperg is a good choice.

If the Google police come knocking, you've never heard of me, OK?

Answer (score 1):

I use http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html . Google Scholar doesn't have API ( http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=109 ). Of course it is not allowed by Google (read terms of use. Automatic requestr are forbidden).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a bit of example code which gets the titles on the first page using the open source product [TestPlan](http://testplan.brainbrain.net/). It is a standalone product, but if you really need it I could help you integrated it into your Java code (it is written in Java itself).

```
GotoURL http://scholar.google.com/

SubmitForm with
    %Params:q% automate theory
end

set %Items% as response //div[@class='gs_r']
foreach %Item% in %Items%
    set %Title% as selectIn %Item% h3
    Notice %Title%
end
```

This produces output like the below (my IP is Germany, thus a german response).  Obviously you could format it however you like, or write it to a file; this is just a rough test.

```
00000000-00 GOTOURL http://scholar.google.com/
00000001-00 SUBMITFORM default
00000002-00 NOTICE [ZITATION] Stochastic complexity in statistical inquiry theory
00000003-00 NOTICE AUTOMATED THEORY FORMATION IN MATHEMATICS1
00000004-00 NOTICE Constraint generation via automated theory formation
00000005-00 NOTICE [BUCH] Automated theorem proving: after 25 years
00000006-00 NOTICE [BUCH] Introduction to the Theory of Computation
00000007-00 NOTICE [ZITATION] Computer-controlled systems: theory and design
00000008-00 NOTICE [BUCH] … , randomness & incompleteness: papers on algorithmic information theory
00000009-00 NOTICE [BUCH] Automatic control systems
00000010-00 NOTICE [BUCH] VLSI physical design automation: theory and practice
00000011-00 NOTICE Singular Control Systems.
```